# Have npm regenerate node_modules/.bin symlinks

Tags: node.js, npm

If something has nuked the top level `node_modules/.bin` – is there a way to tell `npm` to regenerate the symlinks there, short of nuking all of `node_modules` and running a fresh `npm install`?

Comment: When using `npm-cache install` the `node_modules/.bin` folder on Ubuntu contains files of 0 byte length that are not symlinks. Would be nice to be able to fix the symlinks after `npm-cache install`. Did you find a solution?

Comment: Nah, I just found the nuke and repeat hack I already had.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It looks like `npm rebuild` should do the trick. It worked for me.

---

See: https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v9/commands/npm-rebuild#bin-links

From the above link:

> `bin-links`
>
> - Default: true
> - Type: Boolean
>
> Tells npm to create symlinks (or `.cmd` shims on Windows) for package executables.
>
> Set to false to have it not do this. This can be used to work around the fact that some file systems don't support symlinks, even on ostensibly Unix systems.

Comment: Worked for me as well (I ran npm from within a WLS Ubuntu on Windows which wouldn't generate the scripts for Windows and npm rebuild fixed it...